# Disable button while loading data in swt

Tags: java, multithreading, button, swt, jface

In my application i have fetch button which fetch some content (takes about 1 min to do that). I want to disable this fetch button while loading the data. I have set

```
fetchButton.setEnable(false);
```

after user click on the button. But sometimes it disable the button, sometimes button is still enabled(I think it is happening due to some threading).

Here is my oversimplified code

```
    fetchButton.addSelectionListener(FetchData);        

    public SelectionAdapter FetchData= new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                fetchButton.setEnable(false);

                Runnable job = new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doSomeHeavyTask();  
                    }
                }
                BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), job);
    };
```

Then new code after modification

```
    fetchButton.addSelectionListener(FetchData);        

    public SelectionAdapter FetchData= new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
            fetchButton.setEnable(false);

            cursor = new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_WAIT);
            Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().setCursor(cursor);

            Thread Job = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    doTask();
                }
            };
            Job.run();

            cursor = new Cursor(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.CURSOR_ARROW);
            Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell().setCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: You need to do your heavy task in a separate thread. The main thread need to be free to update the UI.

Comment: i am doing the heavy task in thread that i created in the same function

Comment: How are you running `job`?

Comment: I am using the busy indicator to run the job  BusyIndicator.showWhile(Display.getCurrent(), job);

Comment: `BusyIndicator` uses the UI thread and is not suitable for long jobs

Comment: So should i create a separate thread for it?

Comment: I have created the separate thread and now i am not using the BusyIndicator but i am still getting the same error. I will add the new code to the question

Comment: You must use `start()` not `run()` on a thread to run it in a new thread.